# Why my display function of linked list always printing the last element?

Tags: java, linked-list

My dipslay function of linked list is as follows:-

```
public void display()
{
    cur = first;

    if(isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("no elements in the list");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("elements in the list are:");

        do {
            System.out.println(first.data);
            first = first.link;
        } while(first.link!=null);

        first=cur;
    }
```

where `curr` and `first` are references of class node

```
public class node
{
      int data;
      Node link=null;
}
```

why is this function only printing the last element?

Comment: If this is homework, add a tag for that. If this is not homework, use `java.util.LinkedList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function looks more or less correct. However why are you setting `cur` to `first` and then using `first` to do the iteration? Just use `cur` in the iteration so you don't have to reset `first`.

Check to make sure you're adding nodes into the list correctly. So if you think there are 3 elements in the list, run this in `display()`:

```
System.out.println(first.data);
System.out.println(first.link.data);
System.out.println(first.link.link.data);
```

This is to check if your links are correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to say for sure, but it is probable that your list actually contains only one element; i.e. that the code that creates the list is broken.

I should also point out that the `display` method should use a local variable to step through the elements.  If you use an instance variable (e.g. `first`) you are liable to get different methods interfering with each other.

Finally, your test for the end of the list is incorrect.  Think carefully about what `first` and `first.link` point at when the `while` test is executed.